# JSF manual refresh issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, refresh

I need your help .

i am developing a simple project with jsf2.0 and primefaces 3.2.

I have 2 pages first is the page1.xhtml whci contains :

```
        <p:column>
            <p:panel header="#{ct.coTypeName}" >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100" height="100">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ct.coTypeId}" />




                    <p:commandLink       action="distributer/distributersList.xhtml">
                        <h:graphicImage  url="/resources/images/homePagecartoonBusinessMan.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
                        <f:param name="bt" value="dist" />
                        <f:param name="ti" value="#{ct.coTypeId}" />
                    </p:commandLink>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

        </p:column>

    </p:dataGrid>
```

When i press The command link it forwarded me to another page "distributer/distributersList.xhtml" which have a selectOneMenu which doesn't show its items until i refresh the page manually that happens only with IE "i am using internet explorer 8" but this issue doesn't happen with chrome or firefox .

i get javascript error ..Webpage error details

```
Message: Object expected
Line: 19
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8089/pro/



Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 5500
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8089/pro/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?          ln=primefaces&v=3.2
```

the selectonemenucode is :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bussinessOwnersViewerMB.selectedCity}" effect="fold" immediate="true"> 

            <f:selectItems value="#{bussinessOwnersViewerMB.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.cityName}" itemValue="#{city.cityId}"/>  


         </p:selectOneMenu>
```

the getter for the cities arraylist is :

```
public ArrayList<CityDto> getCities() {
    cities = cb.laodAllCities();
    System.out.println(">>>>"+cities.size());
        return cities;
}
```

and the system.out.. give me the message with the arraylist size correctly but the dropdownList items doesn't appear until i refresh the page !

Answer (score 0):

If you used f:selectItems tag, you don't need itemLabel and itemValue tags. These tags will need when you use f:selectItem without 's'.Try this sample

```
     <f:selectItems value="#{bussinessOwnersViewerMB.cityList}" var="city">
```

Here is the sample method for getting cities

```
     List<SelectItem> cityList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (City city : cities) {
            SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
            item.setLabel(city.getCityName());
            item.setValue(city.getCityId());
            cityList.add(item);
     }
```

Bind you f:selectItems value with cityList(check the above)that changed original cities list.

Comment: Thanks Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye for your fast reply ,but the data is already shown with my code sample .. tha main problem is that the data aren't shown until i refresh the page .

any way i try your code and as expected the same result ..

thanx again :)

Answer (score 0):

elgohary do one thing dear  take one boolean variable like isLoaded
and put below code in Lode method

`

```
    if (isLoaded)
    {
        return;
    }
    isLoaded = true;
```

`
and where you need to refresh page int that operation please  do below

```
isLoaded=false;
```

Comment: Thanks Jigar Patel ,

but i edit my post with the backing bean and already my managed bean get the arrayList correctly .. and if i redirected to the distributer.xhtml page the SelectOneMenu items appears , but i want to forward it not redirect as i send parameters with the request.